# how to prove a simple graph with this question

Tags: algorithms

) Suppose G is a simple graph with n vertices. Prove that G has twice as many edges as vertices only if n ≥ 5. ?

Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

> Prove that G has twice as many edges as vertices only if n ≥ 5

Rephrased: prove that if $n < 5$, $G$ has fewer than $2n$ edges.

Which simple graph on $n$ vertices has the most edges? How many does it have, as a function of $n$?

Comment: i think n ≥ 5.  already i dont know the answer !

Answer (score 0):

in a graph sum of the degree= 2* number of edges. Let n < 5 then sum of degree is at most n(n-1), so number of edges is at most n(n-1)/2. Let f(n)= n(n-1)/2. It is easy to show that f(n)<= 2n when n<5.